# code coverage report for multiple browsers in Karma

Tags: javascript, node.js, tdd, karma-runner

How to create code coverage reports for all browsers present in Karma configuration file?
My config.js looks like

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [...],
    browsers: ['IE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome'],
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    preprocessors: { '*.js': ['coverage'] },
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : ...,
    },
    singleRun: true
     . . . .
});
};
```

All tests pass fine, but the report is generated only for the browser that finishes last. Json-formatted reports are generated normally for all browsers by the way.

I have

```
 npm of version 1.4.3
```

and

```
node.js of version 0.10.26
```

installed on Win8 x64.

P.S. On Win7 x64 it seems to work: all reports are generated.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too.
Adding the next configuration will generate the coverage report for all browsers:

```
singleRun: true
```

Of course, the drawback is that tests will be ran only one time (the script will exit after that).

Comment: Sorry for not including that line in the code, but `singleRun` was set to `true`. I added some more lines that are always present in my `conf.js`.